# SQL Server Full Text ContainsTable function Rank issue

Tags: sql-server, search, full-text-search, containstable

Is is possible to increase the Rank of the ContainsTable results if its an Exact match.

I have a fulltext query like this

select iname,rank from 
ItemSearch_View sv INNER JOIN 
CONTAINSTABLE(ItemSearch_View,searchstring, '(FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "google") )',500) AS itable ON sv.itemid  = itable.[KEY]
order by rank desc

which provides the following results (right side is the rank)

Googling                         352

Googled Former Teachers,             320

Googled Former Boy/Girl Friends 320

Googled the Guy/Girl                320

Google                          208

Is it possible the item "Google" Item can have the higher rank here.

Thanks
Vijai

Answer (score 1):

I believe the results you are experiencing are due to the use of the INFLECTIONAL clause.

For example, "Googling" is an inflectional match of "Google" and because of the increased length in the word "Googling", produces a higher rank score, i.e. likely to be a higher quality match.

How does the same query differ by merely performing a fuzzy search for the word google rather than looking for inflectional forms?

i.e.

CONTAINSTABLE(ItemSearch_View,searchstring, 'google')